# reledmac+reledpar and figure

Tags: reledpar

EDIT-2  see code below. I fixed it, and it works. My question is whether reledpar may help with what I need. This is to publish - face to face - scans of handwritten letters and their trascripts, for about 100 scans. Code below does not help because it seems I need to insert some dummy text on the leftside, and the final output is: a page with the scan, leftside page with dummy text, rightside page. (scan and dummy text goes within the same page if I downsize scan, but that is not good enough for my present)

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[american,russian,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}  
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart[ 
    {\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{test/001.jpg}
    \end{figure}}   <--- I need to {} code within [], don't I?
    ]  DUMMY TEXT 
    \endnumbering 
\end{Leftside} 
\begin{Rightside}  
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart 
     \input{test/001.tex } 
    \pend   
    \endnumbering  
\end{Rightside} 
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}  
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart[ 
        {\begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=.25]{test/002.jpg}
            \end{figure}}
    ] DUMMY TEXT
    \pend 
    \endnumbering 
  \end{Leftside} 
  \begin{Rightside}  
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart 
    \input{test/002.tex }
    \pend 
    \endnumbering  
 \end{Rightside} 
 \end{pages} 
 \Pages 
 \end{document}
```

ps also, I do not need to show line numbers, is there a option to hide them?

Comment: please, dont send the question on both reledmac list (three time) and here.

Comment: please also provides a full MWE

Comment: @Maïeul  yes, sorry, a mistake

Comment: see my new answer. I don't think reledpar is relevant in your case.

Comment: @Maïeul, I looking at it. Back soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have image on left page and text on right page, I don't think reledpar is relevant for you.

I will do it manually, this way:

```
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{test/001.jpg}
\newpage
transcription
\newpage
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{test/002.jpg}
\newpage
\transcription
```

Maybe a good thing could be to create a customize macro called "transcription".

```
\newcounter{transcription}
\newcommand[1]{%
  \addtocounter{transcription}{1}%
  \includegraphics[scale=.25]{\thetranscription.jpg}%
  \newpage
  #1%
  \newpage
}
\transcription{transcription of p. 1}
\transcription{transcription of p. 2}
```

Comment: Ok, reledpar seems very powerful, but it is not the solution for my present task. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As explained on reledmac list, you must use optional argument of \pstart. The content between a `\pstart` and a `\pend` must be only text.

So do `\pstart[HERE code for inserting figure] text \pend`